# Can I customize custom Google search engine to show or link to the first result only?

Tags: javascript, html, css, api, google-custom-search

I'm making a site for my web dev class that's supposed to act like ai, where the user asks a question about a computer issue and ideally, the main result would be a YouTube tutorial embedded on the site. So the site homepage would just be a search bar in the middle, kind of like google's homepage.

I want the question to just be entered in the search bar(I already designed it in html, css, and javascript) in the middle of the homepage and when the user presses enter, the result page should just be an embeded youtube video spanning the page width.

Realistically, if I were to work on a site like that I'd have to develop my own algorithm, but for demonstrating how the site would look, how can I go about customizing the Google CSE script to result in one embed video, or what's the closest way thing I can do to that.

Is the javascript in google CSE even customizable in that regard?

Also, open to trying any suggested, more open source search API.

I started learning HTML, CSS, and JavaScript this year btw, so I'm sorry if I'm saying anything noobish/dumb

Answer (score 0):

Search engine makes use of crawlers and build indexes to show up results on searches. A search's result is entirely based on how the site was ranked based on the keywords. So in short, no you can not customize the google search result. However you can implement SEO (Search Engine Optimization) on your site in order to have your site show up in search result on any search engine. For starters, you can read more about it here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization

Answer (score 0):

You can. Because you are not customizing how the public sees search results but only yours. However, there is no official customization method provided. You need to fake a Google by setting up a local website or using some user script technology.

Comment: Can you elaborate how setting up a local website and a script would show 1 google result?

Comment: @Replica use website downloader to fetch an offline copy of google homepage and result page, afterwards edit it by webpage designer.